# Factorization of $f(x) = x^n - 1$ into irreducible polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Knowing that $e^{2\pi i \frac{k}{n}} = \cos(2 \pi k/n) + i \sin(2 \pi k/n) = \alpha $ is complex roots of $f(x) = x^n - 1$ and therefore the complex factorization is

\begin{align}
    f(X) &= \displaystyle\prod^{n - 1}_{k = 0} (x - \alpha_k)
\end{align}

How do I factorize into irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$ for odd and even n's? I know that for $(x-1) \mid f(x)$ for all n and if n is even $(x+1)\mid f(x)$ as well. I'm also aware that $(x - \alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha})$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$ that also divides $f(x)$. So the remaining factors most take the form $x^2 - 2x\cos(2 \pi k/n) + 1$. But I fail to see which k's to use in the factorization?

Comment: In general, given a complex factorization of a real polynomial, you obtain the real factorization by pairing conjugate pairs of non-real roots.

Comment: Ah okay didn't know that. Thank you

Comment: That is not hard to see: if $\alpha$ is a non-real root of $P(x)$, then so is $\bar \alpha$, and $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha)$ is an irreducible real polynomial dividing $P(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply, you have two cases:

- If $n$ is even: $n=2m$, the complex roots are pairwise conjugate, except for $k=0$ and $k=m$, so the factorisation is
  $$x^{2m}-1=(x-1)(x+1)\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\Bigl(x^2-2\cos\frac{2k\pi}n x+1\Bigr).$$
- If $n$ is odd: $n=2m+1$, they're pairwise conjugate, except for $k=0$, so we obtain
  $$x^{2m+1}-1=(x-1)\prod_{k=1}^{m}\Bigl(x^2-2\cos\frac{2k\pi}n x+1\Bigr).$$

Comment: Very nice (+1). Perhaps it would be better to write $\frac{n}{2} = m$ resp. $\bigl\lfloor\tfrac n2\bigr\rfloor = m$.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Actually, I wondered whether it was possible to find a unique  formula depending on $n$ that would cover both cases, but found nothing really satisfactory.

Comment: If you want to avoid using $m$, write $x^n=(x-1)(x+1)^{2(\frac{n}{2} - \lfloor\frac{n}{2} \rfloor)} \prod_{k=1}^{\bigl\lfloor\tfrac n2\bigr\rfloor}\Bigl(x^2-2\cos\frac{2k\pi}n x+1\Bigr)$. But I am not sure whether this is more transparent.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I guess you're right. I finally used $m$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, if $\exp[2\pi ik/n]$ has a non-zero imaginary component, re $\sin[2\pi k/n]$, then you have to combine it with its complex conjugate.  Otherwise, you can leave it alone.

**Addendum**
Responding to the OP's comment:

Let $c_1 \equiv \cos(2\pi/5), ~c_2 \equiv \cos(4\pi/5).$ 
Let $s_1 \equiv \sin(2\pi/5), ~s_2 \equiv \sin(4\pi/5).$

Then $(z^5 - 1)$ factors into 
$(z-1) ~\times $ 
$(z - [c_1 + i(s_1)]) ~\times~ (z - [c_1 - i(s_1)]) ~\times $ 
$(z - [c_2 + i(s_2)]) ~\times (z - [c_2 - i(s_2)]).$

This equals 
$(z-1) ~\times $ 
$[z^2 - (2c_1)z + ([c_1]^2 + [s_1]^2)] ~\times~ $ 
$[z^2 - (2c_2)z + ([c_2]^2 + [s_2]^2)].$

This equals 
$(z-1) ~\times $ 
$[z^2 - (2c_1)z + (1)] ~\times~ $ 
$[z^2 - (2c_2)z + (1)].$

Comment: I still can't make it work  though: e.g. wheb $f(x) = x^5 - 1$. Doing as you say I find $\exp(2 \pi i k/5)$ having a non-zero imaginary component when k = 1, 2, 3 and 4. When I combine them with their conjugate I get 4 real polynomials with degree 2. Multiplying them together with (x - 1) I get a polynomial with degree 9 - not x^5 - 1.

Comment: @JohnDK see the Addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help!